# How to add in a new data to a TfRecord by performing a join

Tags: tensorflow, apache-beam, tfrecord

I have a bunch of tensorflow records (I didn't create these). However, I need to add in a few more features by joining in another datasource (a big query table). How can I edit a tf record, do I convert it to a TfDataset or do I need to somehow convert it to a pandas dataframe and join in the data and write out as a tfrecord? Anyone have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have TFExample's in the TfRecord then one approach would be to use beam.io.tfrecordio.ReadFromTFRecord along with a tf parsing function:

...

```
   pipeline
        | "ReadMetadata" >> beam.io.tfrecordio.ReadFromTFRecord(
                file_pattern=<file pattern>)
        | "ParseMetadataFile" >> beam.ParDo(_parseExamples())

class _parseExamples(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        beam.DoFn.__init__(self)

    def process(self, element, feature_dict) -> tf.train.Example:
        example = tf.train.Example.FromString(element)
        # Or something like...
        # example = tf.io.parse_single_example(element, feature_dict)
        # Then something like 
        # t = example.features.feature['new']
        # t = tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[1]))
        yield example
```

Other non-beam specific notes on TFRecord and tf.Example

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord

Comment: how do I then add in the other features into that example? like if i wanted to join in data from a big query table?

Comment: Once you have the Example object you can mutate it with other data and then do the reverse of the reading, using the write to TFRecord. 
If the lookup values in BigQuery are small then you can use a beam SideInput , if they are large then use a join within the beam pipeline.

Comment: is there an example of that anywhere? i'd like to see how you mutate it with an external data source. (the join on key as well). and when you rewrite it do you have to reseralize the tf record? does that mean redefining all the features and the types all over again?

Comment: Side inputs: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs
Joins https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey

For output you reseralize the Example to byte and use TFRecordIO write.